# REGEXP_REPLACE not replacing a new character

Tags: sql, regex, exasolution, exasol

I need to replace all instances where a new line is not followed by a colon. This is because colon indicates the start of a new record (a record may span multiple lines).

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(raw,'(\n[^:])','this is a test')
```

For example, with the input:

```
:[MY DATA HERE]
[rest of record printed here]
```

produces the output:

```
:[MY DATA HERE]
this is a testrest of record printed here]
```

instead of:

```
:[MY DATA HERE]this is a test[rest of record printed here]
```

Note that the current output replaces the first non ':' character but not the new line. Does anyone know why this is not working as expected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The regexp matches the newline and the character after it, and replaces both of them.

Comment: Does EXASolution allow you to use back-references in the replacement string? Or do they support negative lookaheads?

Comment: Yes they do, but I'm not sure how to use them https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/regexp_replace.htm

Comment: It should replace the newline and the character after but the output still has the newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the newline and the character after it. You need to capture the character after it, and put that in the replacement. You can refer to capture groups using `\number`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(raw,'\n([^:])','this is a test\1')
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/regexp_replace.htm)

Exasol also supports PCRE, so you should be able to use a negative lookahead:

```
REPLACE_REGEXP(raw, '\n(?!:)', 'this is a test')
```

These differ in one subtle way: Your regexp won't match a newline at the end of the string, since there's nothing to match `[^:]` there. The negative lookahead will match at the end.

Comment: thanks, this improves it by one point - it doesn't replace the first character on the new line but the newline still isn't being replaced

Comment: Are you sure it's `\n` rather than `\r`? I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't replace the newlines.

Comment: shoot me now plz